# Painting in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, repaint

My app needs to display information (lines and rectangles). I was thinking of using JPanel, but I am not sure.

The problem is that the information is stored in a DB, but when the app is launched, eventually new information will get into the DB, and should be displayed as well. Also, the existing displayed information must remain.

Also, it would need at leats two zones for displaying info. One for lines and another for rectangles. Both with the problem of incoming information.

What is the (best) way to add new elements to a graphic without loosing what has been displayed before?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`Canvas`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) and [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) ([Tutorial](http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutorg.htm)). You need to add the `Canvas` to a `JContainer` for example `JPanel`. With [`JDBC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) you can connect to a Database and execute SQL Statement.